# ` (backtick) is unexpected token

Tags: ruby, bash

I'm doing some command line executions I learned in [this blog post](http://mentalized.net/journal/2010/03/08/5_ways_to_run_commands_from_ruby/) such as `system` or `IO.popen` on the file, and am getting errors.

Why is the backtick appearing, what does it mean, and how do I continue? Please explain.

```
 system('./err.rb')
-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `'./err.rb''
```

Similarily, when I run `IO.popen`:

```
output = IO.popen('./err.rb')
-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('
```

Comment: Please post a minimum code snippet that exhibits the problem.

Comment: Bash is trying to interpret your ruby script directly. What did you put in its very first line?

Comment: @user1647484 Just to make sure that you dont take `popen` as similar to like of `system` and `backtick` command make sure you read throughly about popen in ruby doc it bit different from `system` and `backtick` . Although your invocation of popen has nothing to do with it

Comment: @user1647484 Please paste the code of the file `err.rb`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's not ruby you're typing things into, it's your shell bash. Assuming you've got ruby installed properly, type `irb` to get a ruby prompt and you should be able to proceed from there.

Answer (score 2):

Whether in Ruby or bash, `` `...' `` is a meta expression used in places like error messages to quote the problematic part of the code. For example, in your error message: `` unexpected token `(' ``, the problematic part is `(`. Backtick itself has nothing to do with the error.